# File not found error when using a string filepath

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm writing a parsing program that requires the use of model files,  I have to use pre-existing code that requires the path of the models as a string

`Tool lemmatizer = new Lemmatizer("path/to/model");`

However no matter how I try to input the path via hard-coding it or using uri e.g.

`Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://MateToolsAnd/raw/lemmatizer");`

No matter where I put it in both res/raw and assets I keep getting a file not found error, what am I doing wrong?

I should add that the parsing is done in another project and is referenced as a library to the main application

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this：

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lemmatizer);
    try {
        int length = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        is.read(buffer);
        sb.append(EncodingUtils.getString(buffer, "gb2312"));
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
```

I only provide an example,it is not a result for your question
I am sorry for my bad english